# Border-left in menu messing with layout

Tags: css, layout, border

I'm having a hell of problem with a "simple thing".
When i add a border-left to the menu, it pushes the same number of pixels to the right.

Look at the images below:

[MENU WITHOUT BORDER-LEFT](http://s21.postimg.org/n6ubz6mvb/image.png)

[MENU WITH BORDER-LEFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIa7s.png)

It sucks. I'm only a few steps from publishing my website and it's a big headache. I tryied everything, even firebug could not help me.

I then went to the original wordpress theme for some light: **demo.mythemeshop.com/truepixel/**  ---  and switched the box-shadow for border in firebug and got theme same thing, but with the opposite border.

I dont know more what to do. I messed with backup style.css, header.php, trying to add clear div, etc, really need help here.

A simple border smashing me.

Comment: Please include your code or an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really help if you would post the actual code. The only thing I can think of without seeing is to try implementing border-box in your CSS.

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This helps to maintain a border inside a box without adding to the size of the box. Even though you have it set to 100%, the CSS will still add the border to the outside of the box. You can learn more [here](http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/).